# Document saving working sometimes but not others?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a script that copies a .docx template, copies it to a different location with a unique name, modifies it, then saves it.  Occassionally, on the save, I get an file permission error.  It's weird because I will be using the same inputs and sometimes the error will show up and other times it won't.  Here's my code:

```
        File.Copy(Utilities.GetTemplateFilePath(), outputPath);

        object path = outputPath;
        object readOnly = false;
        object o = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        var document = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref o, ref readOnly, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);

        PopulateField(document.Paragraphs, 19, "aValue");
        while (true) {
            try {
                document.Save();
                break;
            }
            catch {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }

        var documentClose = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document)document;
        documentClose.Close();
```

Another important hint is that when this problem occurs, there are .tmp files that are hanging around in the directory I'm writing to. Any idea what is going on here?

> Error: Word cannot complete the save due to a file permission error.
>   (C:...\Document.docx)

Comment: Don't ever hide exceptions like that. Get rid of that try/catch block and maybe you'll find out what's wrong.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, I added the error to the OP.  It's pretty vague, so I'm having trouble figuring it out.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hanging because you are not disposing of the COMInterop Object
try adding this code after you do the document.Close()

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject( document  );
```

Comment: Can you explain why this would only cause problems somteimtes and not others?  I don't doubt you, I'm just curious to know more about this.   Thanks.

Comment: Because the way that we free Objects in C# vs COM Interop objects is totally different.. read up on how to Marshal Com objects

Comment: I got the error again after implementing your solution.  I added the error code to the OP.  Thanks1

Comment: You should not get that error.. It looks like the problem is also in how you created  / tried to cast the document object.. can you paste the full code so I can help you clean this up

Comment: The document definition is in the OP, the only thing I left out is how the word variable is defined: Word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

Comment: That's what I am looking to see